# HAProxy backend sessions limits to 5000 by default. How to change it?

Tags: proxy, server, load-balancing, haproxy

Loadbalancing between 2 servers.

`global` part already has `maxconn 75000`

First `server` has `maxconn 30000` and second `server` has `maxconn 40000`

On the **Statistics Report** page, on the backend table, **Sessions Limit** shows correctly for both server. However, it is set to `5000` for the `backend` line.

The number of current connections is relatively low at this time, but what would happen if the total for both servers exceed that limit of `5000`?

What setting changes that limit for backend?

Comment: it is `fullconn`

Comment: Thank you, @nustercacheserver, that's it!